# wired connections having limited connectivity after connecting to a hub

Tags: router, internet, connection

In my company, there are 4 wired connections to the router. It was all going well but recently, the connectivity has been stopping on 3 of them sometime in the afternoon every day. On all of the computers, there are NO default gateway when i go cmd and ipconfig, but on the three that are unable to access the internet, pinging 8.8.8.8 will result in 4 general errors while the one that can wont.

This problem is really bugging me and my colleagues, any kind souls willing to help?

Comment: From where hub is getting the connection? Try connecting directly and check.

Comment: Ive just connected a few of the computers to the router directly, but its still no good, thanks :)

Comment: Any problem with your ISP? Have you checked.